# Error when making a dash DataTable filterable by columns values

Tags: python, reactjs, plotly-dash

Only when I add the property `filter_action="native"` in a `dash.DataTable` in order to make it possible for the user to filter rows by column values I get an error that varies with the browser I run the webapp on:

- Edge: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'placeholder_text') (This error originated from the built-in JavaScript code that runs Dash apps. Click to see the full stack trace or open your browser's console.) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'placeholder_text') at s.value (http://localhost:8050/_dash-component-suites/dash/dash_table/async-table.js:2:236716)`...
- Chrome: same as Edge
- Firefox: `r is undefined (This error originated from the built-in JavaScript code that runs Dash apps. Click to see the full stack trace or open your browser's console.) value@http://localhost:8050/_dash-component-suites/dash/dash_table/async-table.js:2:236702`...

Note that without setting that single property the app works perfectly.

I terribly need the user to be able to filter rows by column values: what can I do to solve this issue?

### environment

python 3.7, Flask 2.2.2, dash 2.8.0

Comment: It would help if you could share your code. It sounds like your table may not be populated with a value at some point, perhaps initially, and that's why it's undefined, and causing an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a possible solution: that is giving also the `columns` attribute during `DataTable` declaration (no, giving just `data` is not sufficient):

```
columns=[{"name": i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns]
```

The minimal code for making a `DataTable` with working filtering of rows based on column values is

```
dash_table.DataTable(
   id='my_table_id',
   columns=[
      {"name": i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns
   ],
   data=df.to_dict('records'),
   filter_action="native",
)
```

Comment: I was getting the same error and setting columns to empty list fixed it, thanks!

Comment: worked for me. Empty columns did not show error but did not display the table also.